# Get latest record for each group in ElasticSearch nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I want to group by "name" for my nested field. and sort by "submitDate" for each group, then get the latest one record document contents. It that possible?
e.g.
name1 just get the doc2
name2 just get the doc3
name3 just get the doc1

my data

| title | type | stash(nested filed) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| doc1 | type1 | [{"name":"name1","submitDate":"2020-01-04"},{"name":"name2","submitDate":"2020-01-03"},{"name":"name3","submitDate":"2020-01-01"}] |
| doc2 | type1 | [{"name":"name1","submitDate":"2020-01-01"},{"name":"name2","submitDate":"2020-01-02"},{"name":"name3","submitDate":"2020-01-03"}] |
| doc3 | type1 | [{"name":"name1","submitDate":"2020-01-02"},{"name":"name2","submitDate":"2020-01-01"},{"name":"name3","submitDate":"2020-01-02"}] |
| doc4 | type1 | [{"name":"name1","submitDate":"2020-01-02"},{"name":"name2","submitDate":"2020-01-01"},{"name":"name3","submitDate":"2020-01-02"}] |
| doc5 | type2 | [{"name":"name1","submitDate":"2020-01-02"},{"name":"name2","submitDate":"2020-01-01"},{"name":"name3","submitDate":"2020-01-02"}] |

search

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "stash_name": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "stash"
      },
      "aggs": {
              "top_result": {
              "terms":{
                "field": "stash.name",
                "top_hits": {
                  "size": 1,
                   "_source": ["stash.name"],
                    "sort": {
                      "stash.submitDate" : "desc"
                    }
            }
                }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

mapping

```
{
  "my_index_01" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "true",
      "properties" : {
        "col1" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "col2" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "stash" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "dynamic" : "true",
          "properties" : {
            "age" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fielddata" : true
            },
            "submitDate" : {
              "type" : "date"
            }
          }
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "type" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```